# Massive Bluescreens after Electricity-Variablity

Tags: windows-7, bsod

our complete House has Electricity-variability since 2 hours. 
Lights go on / off etc.

Shortly after I recognize it the first time it seems to damaged my computer.
After a further electricity-variability the monitor get's dark and the computer restarted.

Since then I get one bluescreen after another.
Sometimes it says "IRC not less or equal" sometimes "System service exception".

I can start Windows normally without problems, I can stay in the login-screen for hours without problems. Shorty after login I get a bluescreen and restart.
I tried Safemode also, no difference: shortly after login it restarts.

I have Windows 7 Ultimate, 90% of my data is saved on online stores and external HDDs, but a re-installation needs around 5-6 hours for me, so it would be nice not to do it.

Any ideas that would help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.

1.) [Run chkdsk](http://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=6565) by booting from a W7 Repair or Install DVD

once this is done,

2.) [Run a SFC](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-sfc-offline-windows-7-vista/) from the same boot DVD

Answer (score 1):

Could be software OR hardware.  Improper shutdowns can wreak havoc with software.  Hardware is fairly tolerant of voltage excursions, but can fail as a result.  You could try swapping out your current hard drive(s) for a blank one and doing a base install on the blank hard drive to verify your other hardware without having to erase any existing data.  Or, you could try swapping power supplies and whatever other spare hardware you have to see if that's it.